# Add output column based on conditions from another dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataset

```
job Education   Age   Number of relatives   
1   1            25          5  
1   2            23          20 
3   4            26          50 
2   1            37          100    
4   3            29          34 

output    Job   Education   agemin  agemax  relativesmin    relativesmax
Category1   1   1            25      34       1                 11
Category2   2   3            35      44       11                50
Category3   3   2            45      100      50                200
```

so the question is how to add column output in first dataset but based on conditions( df1.job == df2.Job ... and age is between agemin and agemax from second dataset)  the output should look like this :

```
job Education   Age   Number of relatives    output 
1   1            25          5                Category1
1   2            23          20               Category2
3   4            26          50               Uncategorized
2   1            37          100              ....
4   3            29          34               ....
```

i've tried several ways inculuding iterrows and join the two datasets but i dont get the result i need formy case

Comment: do you know about `merge_asof`? this should help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC,

we can merge then use a simple filter with column assignment :

```
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.lower()
df_new = pd.merge(df1, df2[["job", "agemin", "agemax", "output"]], on="job", how="left")

df_new.loc[
    ~((df_new["Age"] >= df_new["agemin"]) & (df_new["Age"] <= df_new["agemax"])), "output"
] = "Uncategorised"
```

---

```
print(df_new)

   job  Education  Age  Number_of_relatives  agemin  agemax         output
0    1          1   25                    5    25.0    34.0      Category1
1    1          2   23                   20    25.0    34.0  Uncategorised
2    3          4   26                   50    45.0   100.0  Uncategorised
3    2          1   37                  100    35.0    44.0      Category2
4    4          3   29                   34     NaN     NaN            NaN
```

Comment: job Educ   Age N_rel    amin  amax   output 
2 3    46  90      35.0  44.0   Category2
in this row age is not between 35 and 44 but i still get category2 
that's the only problem i've found

Comment: df_new.loc[~((df_new["Age"] >= df_new["amin"]) & (df_new["Age"] <= df_new["amax"])) , "output"] = "Uncategorised"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using [`IntervalIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_arrays.html) with [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
s = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['agemin'],df2['agemax'],'left')
d = df2.set_index(s).reindex(df1['Age']).loc[:,['output','Job']]
         .groupby(level=0,sort=False).first().set_index('Job',append=True))
final = (df1.set_index(['Age','job']).assign(**d)
           .fillna({'output':'Uncategorized'}).reset_index())
```

---

```
print(final)

   Age  job  Education  Number_of_relatives         output
0   25    1          1                    5      Category1
1   23    1          2                   20  Uncategorized
2   26    3          4                   50  Uncategorized
3   37    2          1                  100      Category2
4   29    4          3                   34  Uncategorized
```

Comment: ir raises a cannot handle a non-unique multi-index! error

Comment: @AidouniIsmail right, I edited a little with a test case. Should work now though for this use case Datanovice's answer is more readable